# How to pass spark parameter to a dataproc workflow template?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

Here's what I have:

```
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates create $TEMPLATE_ID --region $REGION

gcloud beta dataproc workflow-templates set-managed-cluster $TEMPLATE_ID --region $REGION --cluster-name dailyhourlygtp --image-version 1.5 
--master-machine-type=n1-standard-8 --worker-machine-type=n1-standard-16 --num-workers=10 --master-boot-disk-size=500 
--worker-boot-disk-size=500 --zone=europe-west1-b


export STEP_ID=step_pyspark1

gcloud dataproc workflow-templates add-job pyspark \
gs://$BUCKET_NAME/my_pyscript.py \
--step-id $STEP_ID \
--workflow-template $TEMPLATE_ID \
--region $REGION \
--jar=gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar
--initialization-actions gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar
--properties spark.jars.packages=gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar

gcloud dataproc workflow-templates instantiate $TEMPLATE_ID --region=$REGION
```

So here the question is how do I pass the following spark parameter to my `my_pyscript.py`:

```
--master yarn     --deploy-mode cluster     --conf "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=900" 
--conf "spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=10485760" --conf "spark.executor.memoryOverhead=8192" 
--conf "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true" --conf "spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true" 
--executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 15g --driver-memory 16g
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in the documentation [gcloud dataproc workflow-templates add-job pyspark](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/workflow-templates/add-job/pyspark):

> ```
> --properties=[PROPERTY=VALUE,…]
> ```
>
> List of key value pairs to configure PySpark. For a list of available properties, see:
> https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#available-properties.

So you would do as when you [submit pyspark jobs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/pyspark) to dataproc cluster without a template. The spark properties for the submitted job are passed as an array of key-values via `--properties` parameter.

If your python job expects args, you specify them on the right of the positional argument [`--`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/pyspark#JOB_ARGS) and separated by spaces.

For your example, it can be done like this:

```sh
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates add-job pyspark \
gs://$BUCKET_NAME/my_pyscript.py \
--step-id $STEP_ID \
--workflow-template $TEMPLATE_ID \
--region $REGION \
--properties="spark.submit.deployMode"="cluster",\
"park.sql.shuffle.partitions"="900",\
"spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold"="10485760",\
"spark.executor.memoryOverhead"="8192",\
"spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled"="true",\
"spark.shuffle.service.enabled"="true",\
"spark.executor.memory"="15g",\
"spark.driver.memory"="16g",\
"spark.executor.cores"="5" \
-- arg1 arg2 # for named args: -- -arg1 arg1 -arg2 arg2
```